# Is there any way to stop this character's death?

Tags: minecraft-story-mode

Is there anyway to stop Reuben from dying?

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no way to stop it. It's a done deal, and you can't do anything about it. Maybe something will change in the next episode, but for now, the death is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

There's no possible way to prevent that character from dying. I tried everything I could. You can't do anything about it. However, some fan theories do think that:

> They plan to revive Reuben by maybe a command block or maybe Jesse will have another pig named Reuben.

There is no way to let him live. A story should always have a bad thing, as said.

Answer (score 0):

There actualy is a way to save Ruben.

You have to take a potion of healing in the 1st episode from when you throw it at the wither.  Just don't throw it.  Keep it in your inventory the whole time until Ruben comes out then it will give you the option to revive him.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: This is FAKE! I knew this because I decompiled and read the game's lua source files using ttarchext and unluac.